# Interval keep changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

So in my code, if an element is not doing something [`playing`] then I'll start playing it. If it's playing, stop the thing. I managed to make it start playing but it never stop.

```
var playing = false;
var current = 30;
$('#countDownContainer').click(function() {
        if (!playing) {
            playing = false;
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#workSpace label').get(0).innerHTML = current;
                current -= 1;
            },1000);
        } else {
            playing = true;
        }
    });
```

In theory, when user click `#countDownContainer`,`playing` would be set to false and run the `setInterval` code and if it's already playing, `playing` would be set to true and when go through the loop it wouldn't run. But in fact, it keep changing from `30` to `29` and back to `30`.And it never stop when I clicked the button again. please help -thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var clear= setInterval(function() {
                    $('#workSpace label').get(0).innerHTML = current;
                    current -= 1;
                },1000);

    clearinterval(clear);// to stop interval where you want
    //clearInterval(id_of_setinterval)
```

reference [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you have mixed up your var `playing` assignments.
You should also assign the ID returned from `setInterval` so you can later abort that intervalled loop with `clearInterval`:

```
//initialize var at the start of the script
var intervalID;

// in the onclick event
if (!playing) {
    playing = true; // should be true here
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        $('#workSpace label').get(0).innerHTML = current;
        current -= 1;
    },1000);
} else {
    playing = false; // should be false here
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

See the [documentation on clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval)

Comment: got another problem: It never stop.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [logic error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error).

Because note the following:

```
var playing = false;         // playing is initialised to false

if (!playing) {              // if not playing
        playing = false;     // set playing to false
```

Hence `playing` can never become `true`.

You can solve by doing the following:

```
var playing = false;
var current = 30;
$('#countDownContainer').click(function() {
    if (playing) {
        playing = false;
    } else {
        playing = true;
         setInterval(function() {
            $('#workSpace label').get(0).innerHTML = current;
            current -= 1;
        },1000);
    }
});
```

Or in words:

If not `playing`, we make it playing hence: `playing = true;`

If `playing`, we make it not playing hence: `playing = false`

**Addendum**

For the stop problem, please refer to @Riturajratan his question.